# How to give access to RAPIDSTART in Business Central to SUPER user?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central

I'm using a SUPER user in Business Central.

When I try to use Rapidstart to create or edit a configuration package it seems that I don't have permissions:

[image]

This is my user groups:

[image]

User permissions:

[image]

So, it's SUPER and it has the RAPIDSTART group and permission set... But still not able to use RAPIDSTART... How can I give this user access to RAPIDSTART?

Answer (score 2):

Well, just 1 hour after posting the question, the customer just remembered that he took my license for another user and forgot to assign it back to my user...

So I wasn't able to use Rapidstart because of the license and everything was looking fine in BC.

This might be useful for someone that finds everything fine inside Business Central, just go into your Admin Center and look for your license. You should see something missing there.